# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Management - MDM after redirection issue "/admin/samlsso"

Tags: wso2, enterprise, mdm

> ```
> https://192.168.1.100:9443/  with this link , im connecting and when i click to Mobile Device Management link in left side of the page
> ```
>
> , appears a note (you r redirecting now please wait).After this
>   redirection , url is being like that
>
> ```
> https://192.168.1.100/admin/samlsso
> ```
>
> and nothing done. What is my problem ?    i just be able to connect
>   to this url; `https://192.168.1.100:9443/admin/carbon/admin/login.jsp`
>
> i can login.But i cant login
>
> ```
> "MDM - https://192.168.1.100:9443/mdm/login".
> ```

**i re-install server and its working now thanks for all**

---

Actually , i could not reach Mobile Device Management Panel , with `https://localhost:9443/` this. im getting home page of product , there is images with links. Left side of page i'm clicking the Mobile Device Management image and im redirecting to this . `https://192.168.1.100/admin/samlsso` and i m getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(google chrome empty page).
  what is wrong ?

NOTE: while server starting , i'm not getting any error .
NOTE: The same issue also for `https://localhost:9443/mam/login` (App Management Console) , i just reach `https://localhost:9443/store/` page. And `https://localhost:9443/admin/carbon/admin/login.jsp` page :/

Comment: Are you redirected to `https://192.168.1.100/admin/samlsso` but not to `https://192.168.1.100:9443/admin/samlsso`?

Comment: yes but  , when i enter the this link  "https://192.168.1.100:9443/admin/samlsso " manually , i still not reached anything . not oppening any page.

Answer (score 1):

In the sso-idp-config.xml, you need to give the port along with your IP (192.168.1.100:9443) or leave it as localhost if you are accessing the MDM from the same machine you are running the server (wso2server.sh)